# I wish to perform the same operation for a column in my Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, data-science

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/todA5.png)

As you can see CallId is repeated, but the data (time) is not.
I need to know or shortest time of each CallId.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpLo8.png)

I get the shortest result of time when I specify CallId, but it will be very laborious when I have over 550 different CallId.
I'm new to Python, but I think it has a simpler way to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.Series.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) on the `CallId` column. This will give you a set of all unique values in that column. Then loop over that result and [`pandas.DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) the DataFrame for each unique value to get sub-dataframes containing only entries for each unique CallId. Then calculate the minimum of the `Data` column in the queried DataFrame:

```py
# all unique CallId's
unique_callids = entrou.CallId.unique()
# loop over the unique CallId values
for ucid in unique_callids:
    # query the main dataframe to get a sub-dataframe of only CallId == ucid
    ucid_entrou = entrou.query("CallId == {}".format(ucid))
    # calculate the minimum of `Data` for this sub-dataframe
    min_ucid = ucid_entrou.Data.min()
```

Comment: But when I run this code still comes a syntax error:

Comment: File "C:\Users\Isaque - CX\Anaconda3\lib\ast.py", line 35, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)

  File "<unknown>", line 1
    CallId ==000 3 -1571053260.3665620
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: It looks like CallId is a string; try instead: `entrou.query("CallID == '{}'".format(ucid))`